# Drag and Drop onto ArcGIS Runtime WPF Map

Tags: arcgis-10.1, wpf, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for advice on implementing drag & drop onto the WPF map control. My goal is to drag from a list of items, and drop on the map to create a new graphic/feature at the drop location.

The map has Drop and PreviewDrop events, but neither provide the map/mouse coordinates of the drop event. Am I missing something in the events? Both have DragEventArgs as the parameter.

All I really need is the mouse's map position when the drop happens. With that in mind, I also tried to get mouse move events, but they don't seem to carry any position either, only MouseEventArgs.

Any ideas? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

P.S. ArcGIS Runtime 10.1.1, but I can upgrade to 10.2 if there is something that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got pointed in the right direction from Antti Kajanus on the ESRI forum. Here is the relevant Drop method:

```cs
private void Drop(object e)
{
    var args = e as DragEventArgs;
    if (args == null)
        return;

    var mousePosition = args.GetPosition(_map);
    var mapPoint = _map.ScreenToMap(mousePosition);

    if (_map.WrapAroundIsActive)
        mapPoint = Geometry.NormalizeCentralMeridian(mapPoint) as MapPoint;

    var graphic = new Graphic();
    graphic .Geometry = mapPoint;

    MyLayer.Graphics.Add(graphic );
}
```

I have posted a complete sample application at https://github.com/keithgemeinhart/ArcGis.Wpf.DragDropDemo

A couple of key points ....

I use the GalaSoft MVVM Light library to get an implementation of EventToCommand. The provides a mechanism for mapping an event to a command in the view model. For example:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers >
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MapLoadedCommand, Source={StaticResource DragDropViewModel}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This maps the Loaded event on the map to the MapLoadedCommand in the DragDropViewModel. That's a key event because we need a means for getting a map reference into the view model. So my solution was to capture the map reference as a parameter of the map's Loaded event. Here is the implementation in the view model. The last line in the method extracts the map reference from the RoutedEventArgs Source property.

```
private void MapLoaded(object parameter)
{
    // See if the event sent the map in the event args
    var p1 = parameter as System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs;
    if (p1 == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("Cannot capture map reference.");
        return;
    }

    _map = p1.Source as Map;
}
```